# Running matlab predict and nearest K in deployed jar file

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to run a very simple function in matlab that works when I run it there

```
function testFunction
mdl = fitcknn([1,1,1],[1]);
predict(mdl,[1,1,1]);
disp('done')

end
```

however when I compile this into a jar file (and I've tried doing this with multiple MATLAB versions) I get the following error thrown

```
Undefined function 'classreg.learning.modelparams.KNNParams.make' for input arguments of type 'char'.
Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fillIfNeeded (line 517)
Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate.make (line 122)
Error in ClassificationKNN.fit (line 755)
Error in fitcknn (line 263)
Error in testFunction (line 2)
```

Is this because it's impossible to deploy the fitcknn function? If so, what should I do as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line to your code (prior to the function):

```
%#function classreg.learning.modelparams.KNNParams.make
```